# How to prove a bilinear map on Banach spaces is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

this is the problem that I need to sovle and below is my attempted solution. I would greatly appreciate if you could proofread it and let me know if it is alright! :)

Question: Let $X, Y, Z$ be real Banach spaces. Let $B: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that for every $x \in X$ it holds $B(x, \cdot) \in \mathrm{L}(Y, \mathbb{R})$ and for every $y \in Y$ it holds $B(\cdot, y) \in \mathrm{L}(X, \mathbb{R})$. Prove that $B$ is bilinear and continuous.

My Answer:

Let $X, Y, Z$ be real Banach spaces and let $B: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that for every $x \in X$ it holds that $B(x, \cdot) \in L(Y, \mathbb{R})$ and for every $y \in Y$ it holds that $B(\cdot, y) \in$ $L(X, \mathbb{R})$. We want to show that $B$ is bilinear and continuous.

Bilinearity:

To prove bilinearity, we must show that $B$ is linear in each argument.

Linearity in the first argument: Fix $y \in Y$. Since $B(\cdot, y) \in L(X, \mathbb{R})$, it is a linear operator by definition. Hence, for any $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and any scalar $\alpha$, we have $B\left(x_1+x_2, y\right)=B\left(x_1, y\right)+B\left(x_2, y\right)$
and
$$
B\left(\alpha x_1, y\right)=\alpha B\left(x_1, y\right) \text {. }
$$

Linearity in the second argument: Fix $x \in X$. Since $B(x, \cdot) \in L(Y, \mathbb{R})$, it is a linear operator by definition. Hence, for any $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and any scalar $\beta$, we have
$$
B\left(x, y_1+y_2\right)=B\left(x, y_1\right)+B\left(x, y_2\right)
$$
and
$$
B\left(x, \beta y_1\right)=\beta B\left(x, y_1\right) \text {. }
$$

This proves that $B$ is linear in both arguments when the other is fixed, thus $B$ is bilinear.

Continuity:

To prove continuity, we will use the fact that $B(x, \cdot)$ and $B(\cdot, y)$ are continuous and apply the Uniform Boundedness Principle.

For each $x \in X$, since $B(x, \cdot)$ is a continuous linear operator from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a constant $M_x$ such that for all $y \in Y$, we have
$$
|B(x, y)| \leq M_x\|y\| \text {. }
$$

Similarly, for each $y \in Y$, since $B(\cdot, y)$ is a continuous linear operator from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a constant $N_y$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have
$$
|B(x, y)| \leq N_y\|x\| \text {. }
$$

By the Uniform Boundedness Principle, the pointwise bounds on $B$ imply there exist uniform bounds over $X$ and $Y$. Specifically, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|B(x, \cdot)\| \leq N$ for all $x \in X$
and
$\|B(\cdot, y)\| \leq N$ for all $y \in Y$.

This means that $B$ is bounded, which implies continuity. Therefore, we have shown that $B$ is continuous.

Thus, we conclude that $B$ is a continuous bilinear map from $X \times Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Kevin, ok I understand! and thanks a lot. :D